# Get client IP with Header add in Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, x-forwarded-for

I am attempting to get the client IP in a HTTP header. I have seen a lot of references to getting this in Logs however i dont know how this translates to passing it as a header. I was going to use header add like below but dont know how to refer to client IP. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Header add X-Forwarded-For "Client IP"
```

Answer (score 1):

In [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) to expand a variable the syntax is:

> `%{VARNAME}e` :   The contents of the environment variable VARNAME.

If you can use them most modules allow you to use/access the generic generic server variable names as listed [in the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html#vars).

> `REMOTE_ADDR`     The IP address of the remote host

So you end up with something along the lines of:

```
Header add X-Forwarded-For "%{REMOTE_ADDR}e"
```

But typically I would expect that the X-forwarded-For header gets set automatically: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers

Comment: That is returning null. Strangely I can log the IP address using the following:

`LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined

#LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{X-Forwarded-For}i" common

CustomLog /var/log/custom.log common

LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer

LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent`

If you need any more info let me know as I mightnt be explaining myself